# attributeerror '_io.textiowrapper' object has no attribute 'shell'

Tags: python

When I call the function below

```
import sys
import os    
def search_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search, value):
        shell = sys.stdout.shell
        """Search for the given string in file and return lines containing that string,
        along with line numbers"""
        line_number = 0
        
        with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
            for line in read_obj:
                line_number += 1
                if string_to_search in line:
                    y = line.split("value=",1)[1]
                    z = line.split("value=",1)[0]
                    if not value in y:
                        shell.write( "line_number: "+ str(line_number), "COMMENT" )
                        shell.write( z+"  ==> KO !\n", "COMMENT" )
                       
                    else:
                        shell.write( z+"  ==> OK !\n", "STRING" )
```

I meet this error:

```
   attributeError '_io.textiowrapper' object has no attribute 'shell'
```

Please do you know what does it means?

How to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: `sys.stdout.shell` isn't a standard part of Python, it only exists when running your code using IDLE.

Comment: There's no `shell` attribute on `sys.stdout`. If you need *stream to write*, then it is `sys.stdout` itself, and `COMMENT` and `STRING` arguments are not supported (and will cause error). If you need to write colored output not from IDLE, you can use [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/), [`termcolor`](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/), [`ansicolors`](https://pypi.org/project/ansicolors/) or other packages (or use ANSI codes manually, of course, if you want some less maintainable and more error-prone code)